# Opening FireFox from CLI causes X error "cannot open display: 0"

Tags: linux, xorg, xhost

When I try to open FireFox in my Linux machine from the CLI, this error shows up:

```
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

I have tried to set the DISPLAY to a lot of values, :0, :0.0, :1, :1.0, 0...
I have also tried setting DISPLAY to my IP followed by :0.0 and the others listed above.
Is there a way to find what should the DISPLAY be? Or is there any other solution?

Comment: Firefox, typing firefox in terminal

Comment: Rather than answering in comments it's better to [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1774445/edit) the question as I now did for you. That way the relevant info is readily available and the question stays up-to-date.

Comment: Try setting DISPLAY to `'IP:0.0'` where IP is your workstation’s local IP. You may try `127.0.0.1`.